# cancelto goes outside of the brackets

Tags: brackets, cancel

Here is a simple equation:

```
\begin{equation}
    \delta\psi=c\left(\int a\delta b dR+\cancelto{O^2(a)}{\int b\delta a dR} \right)
\end{equation}
```

and the cancelto part goes ouside of the right bracket. Is there a way to keep it inside of the bracket?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `makeroom` option of the `cancel` package:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{equation}
    \delta\psi=c\left(\int a\delta b dR+\cancelto{O^2(a)}{\int b\delta a dR} \right)
\end{equation}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This works for me.

Comment: @yangyang You're welcome!

Answer (score 3):

The idea behind `\cancelto` is that the material at the top of the arrow should be disregarded as far as spacing is concerned.

You can use the `makeroom` option, but this means that the material will *always* occupy the space. However, you can have both options.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\scancelto}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \def\canto@fil{\hfil}%
  \cancelto{#1}{#2}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\delta\psi=c\biggl(\int a\delta b\,dR+\scancelto{O^2(a)}{\int b\delta a\,dR}\biggr)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
x+\cancelto{0}{y-y\mathstrut}=x
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Don't forget `\,` in front of differentials in integrals. Also note that `\biggl(` and `\biggr)` are, in this case, much better than `\left(` and `\right)`.