# Nicer way to cancel whole fraction

Tags: fractions, strikeout

I attempted to utilize `\cancel{}` to strike through entire fractions. While it functions okay for fractions that occupy a small space, it appears slightly awkward for larger fractions. The angle of the crossed line is excessively inclined, causing it to touch with the left parenthesis. Are there alternative methods available for crossing out fractions?
[image]

Edit1: Test document in case someone wants to try it out:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cancel}
\begin{document}
\[
\left(\cancel{\frac{1}{7}}+\cancel{\frac{1}{9}}\right)-\ldots+(-1)^n \left(\cancel{\frac{1}{2n-1}}+\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)
\]
\end{document}
```

Edit2: With `makeroom` option

[image]

Comment: Please add a small, but compilable test document so people willing to help you don't have to start from scratch.

Comment: Ok, assuming it's just an example, which doesn't need to reflect true math ...

Comment: @Terrarium Did you already try the `makeroom` option? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/683759/36296

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Yes, I tried the `makeroom` option. It barely made any difference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Might be a bit overkill, but if you would like full control over the cancel line, you could use the `tikzmark` library:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
\[
\left(\cancel{\frac{1}{7}}+\cancel{\frac{1}{9}}\right)-\ldots+(-1)^n \left(\tikzmarknode{foo}{\frac{1}{2n-1}}+\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)
\]
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw ([xshift=0.2cm]foo.south west) -- ([xshift=-0.2cm]foo.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is a bit overkill, but I believe this is how it should ideally appear.

Answer (score 9):

I suggest inserting `\,` (thinspace) between `\left(` and `\cancel{\frac{1}{2n-1}}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{mleftright}\mleftright
\begin{document}
\[
\left(\cancel{\frac{1}{7}}+\cancel{\frac{1}{9}}\right)-\ldots+(-1)^n 
\left(\,\cancel{\frac{1}{2n-1}}+\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: The crossed line looks slightly longer than ideal, but it still presents a favorable option